# Matlab formatting : wrap line in sprintf 

Tags: matlab, printf

I get the value of output, which corresponds to the diff between 2 files :

```
output = 'a.x: low 0 -> low 1a.b : 3 -> Medium 6'
```

then I `printf` the content

```
sprintf('files are different \n%s', output);
```

but I would like to show it as follows (word wrap):

```
output :

a.x: low 0 -> low 1 
a.b : 3 -> Medium 6
```

Comment: How are you setting the contents of `output`? Seems to me it'd be easier to put these two lines in two separate variables rather than split them up on display...

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to chop your string

```
chopped = regexpi(output, '^(?<line1>[^>]*>[^\d]*[\d]*)(?<line2>.*)$', 'names')
```

does the trick here.

```
>> chopped = 

    line1: 'a.x: low 0 -> low 1'
    line2: 'a.b : 3 -> Medium 6'
```

The assumptions are:

1. you always have one  single `->` in the first line
2. the first line always ends with the first number after `->`
3. the numerical value ending first line in an integer

If you're not familiar with regex

- `(?<line1> )` and `(?<line2> )` are here to capture the matches in the `chopped` variable.
- `[^>]*` consumes until first `>`
- `[^\d]*` consumes all non numerical characters (so until the following number starts)
- `[\d]*` consumes all numerical characters
- `.*` consumes rest of the string